# JSLint says new keyword is missing

Tags: javascript, new-operator, jslint, coding-style

Let's say I have some JavaScript that looks like this:

```
function A() {

  var MyVar, SomeParameter;

  // do work

  MyVar = FunctionB(SomeParameter);

}
```

JsLint says I'm `Missing 'new'. at the line MyVar = FunctionB(SomeParameter);`

Why should I rewrite as `MyVar = new FunctionB(SomeParameter);` Is there going to be any benefit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the [convention](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names) that constructors (eg: `Array`, `Object`) are starting with a capital.

JSLint complains, because it thinks that you're trying to use a constructor, without `new` keyword. To fix the problem, start your function with a non-uppercase character.

Comment: Ok, so it's purely semantical then. Thanks Rob!

Comment: semantical yes, but I should point out that's a convention widely used ^^

Answer (score 5):

JSLint thinks the function is a constructor since it's uppercase. Name your non-constructor functions with an initial lowercase letter and JSLint will stop complaining.