# Why is this function considered to be a constructor by linters?

Tags: javascript, constructor, jslint

I've been rewriting various bits of code I've 'inherited' and come across something I don't understand. Both jslint and jshint think the below function is a constructor, and I have no idea why.

```
function GEReqsDone(failed) {
    if (!failed) {
        alert('Thank you for your submission! The page will now be reloaded.');
        document.location.replace(mwConfig.wgScript + '?title=' + encodeURIComponent(mwConfig.wgPageName) + '&action=purge');
    } else {
        alert('An error occurred while submitting the edit.');
        button.disabled = false;
        button.innerHTML = 'Update price';
    }
}
```

This is a callback from query using $.ajax() that queries the mediawiki API to automatically edit to update a price on a page. If the edit succeeds `failed` is not defined and the page reloads. If it fails, `failed` is set to true and it resets the button used to trigger the update.

`button` is simply a button element, the wg* variables are part of the mediaWiki object here used to access the pagename and url prefix (usually `/index.php`).

Does anyone know why jshint and jslint seem to think this function should be `new GEReqsDone()` rather than `GEReqsDone()`?

Comment: Constructors are the only functions in JavaScript that should start with a capital letter. JSLint/JSHint will see that it starts with an uppercase G and assume it is a constructor.

Comment: It's really that simple? Thanks very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSLint says new keyword is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650392/jslint-says-new-keyword-is-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are the only functions in JavaScript that should start with a capital letter. JSLint/JSHint will see that it starts with an uppercase G and assume it is a constructor.

This is the only convention we have to make sure people know that the function should be used as a constructor. Some people write defensively to avoid people missing the `new` keyword:

```
var SomeConstructor = function () {
    if (!(this instanceof SomeConstructor)) 
        return new SomeConstructor();
}
```